# Meet "uninitialized constant #<Class:0x8d78f18>::Chef::Resource::CookbookFile" when running chef-client

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cookbook

I am using Chef 11.10.0.

I implement a new resource called MyCookbookFile which inherits Chef::Resource::CookbookFile.

And, I am not going to change the provider this moment (So Chef::Provider::CookbookFile will be used).

```
require 'chef/resource/cookbook_file'
require 'chef/mixin/securable'

class Chef
  class Resource
    class MyCookbookFile < Chef::Resource::CookbookFile
      include Chef::Mixin::Securable

      provides :my_cookbook_file, :on_platforms => :all

      # more codes here...

    end
  end
end
```

I met the following error:

```
================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/my-cookbook/resources/my_cookbook_file.rb
================================================================================


NameError
---------
uninitialized constant #<Class:0x8d78f18>::Chef::Resource::CookbookFile


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/my-cookbook/resources/my_cookbook_file.rb:6:in `<class:Resource>'
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/my-cookbook/resources/my_cookbook_file.rb:5:in `<class:Chef>'
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/my-cookbook/resources/my_cookbook_file.rb:4:in `class_from_file'


Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/my-cookbook/resources/my_cookbook_file.rb:

  1:  require 'chef/resource/cookbook_file'
  2:  require 'chef/mixin/securable'
  3:
  4:  class Chef
  5:    class Resource
  6>>     class MyCookbookFile < Chef::Resource::CookbookFile


Running handlers:
[2014-02-17T08:16:26+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete

[2014-02-17T08:16:26+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-02-17T08:16:26+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 1.189243344 seconds
[2014-02-17T08:16:26+00:00] ERROR: uninitialized constant #<Class:0x8d78f18>::Chef::Resource::CookbookFile
[2014-02-17T08:16:26+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

I tried to print and check the LOAD_PATH in my cookbook. It includes:

```
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.0/bin/../lib
```

And the library should be in place:

```
[root@localhost /]$ ll /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.0/lib/chef/resource/cookbook_file.rb 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1598 Feb  6 17:22 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.0/lib/chef/resource/cookbook_file.rb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add *::* before *Chef::Resource::CookbookFile*.

```
 class MyCookbookFile < ::Chef::Resource::CookbookFile
```

And move your *my_cookbook_file.rb* to *libraries* folder of the cookbook, since you use pure Ruby and not LWRP syntax.

Comment: Okay.
I put inside the *libraries* folder.
But when I use the resource in *ANOTHER* cookbook, it gives the following error:

`NoMethodError
-------------
No resource or method named `my_cookbook_my_cookbook' for `Chef::Recipe "test-recipe"'`

My recipe is defined like this:


`    my_cookbook_my_cookbook_file "/tmp/my_template" do
       source "my_template.erb"
       mode 0644
    end`

Comment: You must state `depends 'my-cookbook'` in your _other_ cookbook's _metadata.rb_. And it should be just `my_cookbook_file`.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
class MyCookbookFile < Chef::Resource::CookbookFile
```

to:

```
class MyCookbookFile < ::Chef::Resource::CookbookFile
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response.
But it gives same error.

Comment: @SimonHo What about now? Updated my answer.